# Moving EFI Partition to SSD?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm interested in moving my Kubuntu 18.04.02 partitions to my new SSD.

I've done the required reading ([Moving to an SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636494/moving-to-an-ssd)), but am uncertain about moving the EFI partition.

I'm aware that an EFI partition can be created using gparted, and have already allocated 500MiB for it, but haven't set the flags yet for it on my SSD.

I have a standard install, but my SSD is 500GiB smaller than my original drive, so, as far as I know, I can't use clonezila to transfer everything over. This isn't so much of a problem for me because I use BTRFS backups and have simply sent all the data for the subvolumes over.

Can I simply delete the EFI partition and wipe /dev/sda and set the boot and EFI flags on /dev/sdc1 (My new EFI partition on SSD) and run boot-repair, or do the typical grub-repair procedure, or is there more complexity here?

I've just never messed around with the EFI partitions and don't want to mess up my system for a few days.

Comment: The entries in your UEFI are tied to your ESP by the GUID of the partition. You should houseclean old UEFI entries after creating new entries. You can use efibootmgr  see `man efibootmgr` You can reinstall grub, but Ubuntu's grub likes to install to drive seen as sda, it will need a --force parameter. Boot-Repair should work to create new entries. You can have one ESP per drive. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected Examples of deletion: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743